# Pyomo takes time after IPOPT solver call?

Tags: pyomo

When calling ipopt solver after building a concrete QP model, Pyomo runs internal code before calling the solver. Reading other questions on this topic I understand that Pyomo is converting the model to the format that ipopt can understand. But unfortunately Pyomo takes long time before ipopt starts solving the model. Is there a way to reduce the time for the actual solver call?

Answer (score 3):

I believe that Pyomo default behavior is to write an `*.nl` file, then to call IPOPT to process that file and produce a `*.sol` file. Pyomo then parses back in the `*.sol` file. File IO for creation of the `*.nl` file can be a limiting factor for larger models. The solution would be to use an in-memory interface rather than writing the `*.nl` file, which I believe is a work in progress.

It is also possible that you have room for efficiency improvements in model construction. You can check by seeing how long it takes to reach the `solve()` statement vs. execution of the `solve()` itself.

Comment: Thanks for answering this. The model that I am working is big. I already optimized the model construction part and it takes couple of minutes for the model construction. After it reaches the solve statement, Pyomo runs in the background and takes most of the time until the ipopt is called. What do you mean by in-memory interface for writing .nl file?

Comment: It may be possible to transfer the model information to IPOPT without writing a file to disk (the slow part) by going through CasADi. It's something that's been discussed by the core developers. I'm not sure if there's been movement about it. If you want a concrete answer, you might open an issue on the Pyomo Github page.

Comment: Thanks Qi. I will follow up this topic on Github.